# Is there a way to replace the numbers in a string with the word equivalencies?

Tags: c#, .net, text, numbers

So I have a string that has some numbers in it. This string is going to be specified by the user and therefore, must be able to detect the numbers in the string and change them into the word equivalent. This is what I have so far:

```
string[] numwords = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
int[] nums = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
string sample = "Hello MY naMe is Joe Bloggs 1234567 :-)";
for(int x=0; x<nums.Length; x++)
{
 if (sample.Contains(Convert.ToString(nums[x])))
    {
        int index1 = sample.IndexOf(Convert.ToString(nums[x]));
        sample = sample.Remove(sample[index1],1 );
        sample = sample.Insert(sample[index1], Convert.ToString(numwords[x]));
    }
    
}
Console.WriteLine(sample);
```

I am getting this error:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Arg_ParamName_Name'

Comment: So the desired result string replaced the number 1234567 with onetwothreefourfivesixseven and the number 1.5 will be replaced with one.five?

Comment: Yes that would be the desired output. It's for a project at university around pre-processing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `string.Replace`:

```
string sample = "Hello MY naMe is Joe Bloggs 1234567 :-)";
for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    sample = sample.Replace(nums[i].ToString(), numwords[i]);
}
```

Result: `Hello MY naMe is Joe Bloggs onetwothreefourfivesixseven :-)`

Comment: Nitpick but you need to start from the end, otherwise "ten" won't work

Comment: Yeah I've just decided to remove the ten and replace with "one" or "zero". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Regular Expressions* to match and transform the numbers:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string[] numwords = { 
  "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", 
  "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };

string sample = "Hello MY naMe is Joe Bloggs 1234567 :-)";

var result = Regex.Replace(
  sample,
 "[0-9]+", m =>
  string.Join(", ", m.Value.Select(c => numwords[c - '0'])));

Console.Write(result);
```

**Output:**

```
Hello MY naMe is Joe Bloggs one, two, three, four, five, six, seven :-)
```